# Can only access jQuery.ajax not $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange problem. I have loaded jquery-min javascript in my file. But I can only access jQuery.ajax not $.ajax. $.ajax is said to be undefined. Why is that?

Comment: What other libraries are you using? MooTools, Prototype,... ?

Comment: do u use any other libraries such as prototype that also define $  ? try to read http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Are you loading any other libraries as well?  They can conflict and cause issues.  As you know, you can access stuff by jQuery and you can turn off the $ using (from memory) jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: I guess it's due to the google maps javascript loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix this by using a closure as well.

```
(function( $ ){

    // Your jQuery code here.

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: This is a good practice, even in the absences of an explicit $ conflict.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using another framework which takes the `$` function?

Look into [JQuery's noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) setup

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

You can even assign a different alias to JQuery other than `$`:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
j("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```